# How to submit a form in POSTMAN?

Tags: javascript

This is the website I am trying:

```
http://sspi.imi.gov.my/sspi/index.php?page=sspi/bi
```

This is my POSTMAN setup:

```
Method: POST
URL: http://sspi.imi.gov.my/sspi/index.php?page=sspi/bi
Headers: txtIcNo:123456789012
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWBALl++3tCQLM9PumDwLo+47EBQK0kpGBCCZnEFe62pHOJcCmv8hWz2ba//qD
Content-Type:text/html
```

**Results:**

It did not return the actual results in POSTMAN when I clicked on Send.

**Expected Results:**

It shall return a html page with "Checking result: No restriction"

Comment: what was returned instead?

Comment: I guess you are confused in the way postman is used.It is used to fetch and send data at url endpoints .There is another url where post request after inputting number is forward.

Comment: It's hard to provide any help for that generic of a question but one thing that immediately strikes me as odd is that you're making a POST request and expecting an HTML page in return. Not that it is impossible but very odd indeed. Did you mean to make a GET request?

Comment: I wanna make a POST request to get HTML and I'll do the scraping to get the data that I need. @Gaboik1

Comment: What did you get when you did send the request? What HTTP code specifically?